# Using Pandas I am trying to keep the "Date" Column as the index columns, but the column is being duplicated, Can someone help to get it fixed?

Tags: pandas, indexing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


df = pd.read_csv('History.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df[['Date', 'Close']]
df.index = df['Date']
df.head()
```

[image: Image has the Error output]

Image has the error

Comment: The same ker error here as well

Comment: Your comments have nothing to do with your question. There is no `for` loop in your question. Don't ask follow up questions in the comments, you can ask them in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `df.index`, use `df = df.set_index('Date')`.
Read the set_index() documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Comment: That's Not working, I have already tried by using `set_index`.

Comment: @SawanJawalkar Try `df = pd.read_csv("History.csv", index_col = "Date")`